# What function can transform A*Cos[x]+B*Sin[x] to Q*Sin[x+R] form?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

I've tried several functions related to trigonometric transformations, namely `TrigFactor`, `TrigExpand`, `TrigReduce`, as well as `FunctionExpand` and some others, but none gives me the following result (or similar) which I can verify with `FullSimplify`:

```
FullSimplify[ A Cos[x] + B Sin[x] == Sqrt[A^2+B^2] Sin[x+ArcTan[B,A]] ]
```

Of course, this is not a simplification of the LHS, so it's unreasonable to expect `FullSimplify` to yield it directly, but maybe I'm missing some more functions, which could directly lead me to expression similar to RHS of the above equality (i.e. containing only one $\sin$ or $\cos$ of shifted $x$ instead of superposition of multiple $\sin$-$\cos$es). Are there any such functions?

Comment: Perhaps this function: CosSin[A_ Cos[x_]+B_ Sin[x_]] := Sqrt[A^2+B^2] Sin[x+ArcTan[B, A]]; {CosSin[3 Cos[y]+4 Sin[y]], CosSin[p Sin[z]+q Cos[z]]}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define some new `TransformationFunctions` and `ComplexityFunction` for `Simplify`.

```
tfun[expr_] := 
  expr /. a_ Cos[x_] + b_ Sin[x_] :> Sqrt[a^2 + b^2] Sin[x + ArcTan[b, a]];
cfun[expr_] := 
  Plus @@ (Count[expr, #, {0, Infinity}, Heads -> True] & /@ {Sin, Cos});
```

Then

```
Simplify[A Cos[x] + B Sin[x], TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, tfun}, 
ComplexityFunction -> cfun]
(* -> Sqrt[A^2 + B^2] Sin[x + ArcTan[B, A]] *)
```